# How to print only one single element from vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I have created a few cities through the vector

```
    void World::vytvorMesta()
m_cities.push_back(new City("Kokotkova", 23));
m_cities.push_back(new City("Kokotkovasda", 223));
m_cities.push_back(new City("Kokotkqweova", 231));
m_cities.push_back(new City("Kokotkasdova", 243));
```

and then i need to print them so

```
void World::printInfo2() {
    m_player->printInfo();
    if(m_cities.size()>0){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<m_cities.size(); i++){
            m_cities.at(i)->printInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

so im getting an output

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq6bm.png)

my question is how to get only one from this vectors into output...not all of them and how can i "travel" between them...from vector 1 to 2 etc. and again print them. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C does not have std::vector...

Comment: Your question can be reduced significantly, as you are not looking for a solution a problem that you are experiencing, you simply don't know how to use the vector class.  And if you ask this then you will be told to go off and read about how to use it on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print the first element from your vector (position 0) & call its `printInfo()` method:

```
m_cities.at(0)->printInfo();
```

Same as:

```
m_cities[0]->printInfo();
```

The difference between `at()` & the `[]` operator is that `at()` throws an `out_of_range` exception if you try to access an element outside your vector.

If you want the second element (position 1):

```
m_cities.at(1)->printInfo();
m_cities[1]->printInfo();
```

An so on...